# Why does equation environment not give an error without the amsmath package?

Tags: equations, amsmath, latex-base

As far as I understand the `equation` environment is defined in the `amsmath` package so one would expect an error while trying to compile the following document with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a=b+c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

But I don't get any error while running `pdflatex` on this file an a pdf output with the equation `a + b = c` is generated. How does that work exactly?

Comment: @JosephWright No error and that's the problem.

Comment: @DarthPaghius Why's it a problem? The `equation` environment is part of the kernel.

Comment: @JosephWright But every resource I looked at says its a part of ams math package. Is the amsmath overriding the kernel one?

Comment: Btw, +1, it's a very good question and I'm sure some TeXpert will answer soon. `amsmath` is a package which does many useful in math, but for a simple equation like the one of your MWE, the TeX kernel is enough.

Comment: I don't think `amsmath` is required for using `equation` environment. It is required for doing advanced math display.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Yeah. I was trying to solve some other problem somewhat related to `amsmath` and realized I've been using the `equation` environment without using `amsmath` which made me uncomfortable. People don't usually ask why they are not getting an error!

Comment: @DarthPaghius I'm sure that some of the top users here will give you an exemplary answer! And, of course, most people don't care how things work but only why they don't work. You're very clever :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Do I qualify as a TeXpert? :-)

Comment: @Mico Was my "of course you do" comment removed or I only dreamt of writing it (or maybe I deleted it without wanting to do it). Did you see it?

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Good morning. I definitely remember seeing your friendly reply! You didn't just dream about writing it. If somebody deleted your reply, that would be very weird and bizarre indeed.

Comment: @Mico It's also possible I involuntary removed it, the important thing is you read it :):):) Good morning, TeXnician!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You wrote:

> As far as I understand the `equation` environment is defined in the `amsmath` package

That's not quite correct. The `equation` environment is defined in the LaTeX kernel -- *and* it is redefined if the `amsmath` package is loaded in the preamble.

---

For completeness, here's the relevant code from the file `latex.ltx` (the "kernel"):

```
\@definecounter{equation}
\def\equation{$$\refstepcounter{equation}}
\def\endequation{\eqno \hbox{\@eqnnum}$$\@ignoretrue}
\def\@eqnnum{{\normalfont \normalcolor (\theequation)}}
```

where `\eqno` is a so-called "primitive" instruction that takes `\hbox{\@eqnnum}` as its argument. Basically, `\equation` initiates display-math mode and increments a counter called `equation`, while `\endequation` typesets the equation number (on the far right, by default) and closes display-math mode.

And here's the code from `amsmath.sty`; note that due to the `\renewenvironment` instruction, the code replaces what the kernel provides:

```
\renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
```

This setup is, quite obviously, rather more elaborate than what's performed in the LaTeX kernel. The most important substantive differences arise from the fact that, if `amsmath` is loaded, it becomes possible to insert `split`, `aligned`, and `gathered` environments inside an `equation` environment. In addition, `amsmath` performs some fancy measuring operations, behind the scenes, to figure out if it's necessary to "shove" the equation number down a bit in order to avoid a collision with an overly long equation.

If you're really interested in the details, I would like to encourage you to examine the information contained in the file `amsmath.pdf`. Open a command window and type `texdoc amsmath.pdf` to launch the file in a pdf viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It was never explicitly mention in the places I looked.

Comment: @DarthPaghius - You're most welcome!

Comment: @Mico -- the preferred (by knuth, among others) term for someone really knowledgeable about using tex is "TeXnician".  and regarding amsmath documentation, a better way to study it is from the commented equivalent of `amsmath.sty`, namely `amsmath.pdf`.  at a command prompt on a tex live system: `texdoc amsmath.pdf`

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Many thanks for this suggestion! I've updated the final paragraph in my answer. About TeXperts and TeXnicians: Since TeX.SE features an active user with id `@TeXnician`, it may be prudent not to overuse the term around here, lest we create some major confusion. :-)

Comment: @Mico -- yes, i realize the potential for naming confusion.  fortunately, i don't have to worry about that -- i have a certificate prepared and signed by don knuth that declares me to be an "international TeXnocrat".  (i'm still not sure whether that's a good or a bad thing ...)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I used TeXpert first in this post, I didn't know that the preferred term is TeXnician!